# Webform: how to set confirmation message

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm trying to set a confirmation message on my webform.

I'm using the standard redirect to confirmation page option when a form is submitted.

I clicked every single link in my webform backend and can't find it anywhere. All search results regarding this issue lead to programming a custom module to display a confirmation message in a popup or redirect to a different confirmation page. I don't want to do any of that, just a simple edit of the standard confirmation message.

I've looked through the webform-confirmation.tpl.php file in the module and see that it just prints a $confirmation_message variable. I don't want to edit it there as I want to be able to translate the string in the drupal admin section.

Surely this must be available somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you edit the webform there are four tabs at top right side: Display, Edit, Webform and Results (look at screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/207644/screenshot-webform.jpg). Click on Webform tab. If you don't see this tab you have problem with user rights maybe.

On Webform tab are 3 subtabs: Form components, E-mails and Form settings. You must click on third - Form settings. Finally there is section "Submission settings" where you can setup confirmation message.